# How To Change Extent of An Ungeoreferenced Raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis

After photoshopping a tiff in Photoshop, the tiff loads in QGIS as shown in the photo below. Looking at the raster properties, you can see that the extent of the image was changed somehow by Photoshop. So now it loads with the top lefthand corner being placed where the bottom lefthand corner should be. One of the attached images compares the raster properties for the original and processed images. Note the difference in the extents for the two images.

Task: I would like to change the extent data in the processed image so that it is the same as the original image. I have not been able to find a method to this via Googling.

[image: Extents Before and After Photoshop Processing]

[image: In QGIS, how the image comes up in Georeferencer]

Comment: How about just georeferencing it again? Also, have you made sure your shopping couldn't be done in QGIS?

Comment: Thanks Erik. Re-georeferencing wouldn't work because it would take too long. There's like 100 GCPs as you can see. I have about 20 of these images. 

I have also tried processing in QGIS but problem there is I can only change the brightness and contrast and stretch the histogram to max/min. I need dodge/burn tool capability as well as ability to adjust levels and curves. 

I tried editing one of these images in paint.net and I didn't have this problem so I'll use that and just have to reprocess the images.

Comment: It's not obvious at first glance, that those are your referencing points, especially since there are so many of them. Have you tried looking at/comparing the `exif-data of an shopped and an original image?

Comment: Yeah it's crazy these images I really tried to get them very accurately georeferenced. Overkill. Thanks for the suggestion of the EXIF comparison. I started off doing that, thanks to others here suggesting it, and that exercise led to narrowing things down to this extent issue. It explains what is shown in the images above. The image is being loaded into the Georeferencer program on the wrong side of the X axis. And that's what the difference in the extents seem to show.